# Install Xdebug for LNMP environment based on Docker

Tags: docker, phpstorm, xdebug

The LNMP(linux nginx mysql php^_^) environment based on docker, all of which I am in a container.
At present, xdebug can be used normally.
But i need enter code `herexdebug.remote_host = visitor IP` and our IP is constantly changing.
This is an awkward situation.

And if i set `xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1` to let xdebug handle the automatic return of IP.
Docker's `container` is started in the default bridge mode, so the IP obtained by PHP is the bridge IP.
That is: similar to 172.0.0.1, the IP address of the real client cannot be obtained, so xdebug cannot return correctly.
Xdebug.log logs also have records:

```
Log opened at 2018-07-29 07:39:59
I: Checking remote connect back address.
I: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
I: Remote address found, connecting to :9001.
W: Creating socket for ':9001', getaddrinfo: No such file or directory.
E: Could not connect to client. :-(
Log closed at 2018-07-29 07:39:59
```

This problem puzzled for a long time, still hope ,please not stint grant instruction! Thank you very much

This is my nginx host conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name test.lh.XXX.com;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access_XXX_log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/error_XXX_log;

    index index.html index.htm index.php index.phtml;
    client_max_body_size 100m;

    set $public_root /home/xxx/www/xxx_xxx_www/public;
    root $public_root;

    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/(.*)  /index.php?/$1 last;
    }



    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ $uri=404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

    }
}
```

This is my nginx fastcgi_param

```
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

Comment: Try DBGp Proxy (separate software) -- may work. Clint will register at proxy first, Xdebug will connect to proxy and then proxy will send it to the right IP. **P.S.** What is LNMP? `N` stands for "Nginx"? If so .. then the proper name would be LEMP (`E` because of the way how you pronounce the "nginx"). **P.P.S.** About IP detection -- maybe you have not configured nginx properly and it does not pass all needed headers to PHP?

Comment: LNMP is linux nginx mysql php ^ _ ^
and i use php's $_SERVER  can get the client's IP address, but it is 172.0.0.1
X-forwarded -For is empty.

Comment: https://lemp.io/ -- check why LEMP and not LNMP.

Comment: It's nginx's read engine X
But what does it have to do with this?

Comment: No relation -- that's why I've put it under "P.S." section.

Comment: .^_^.
linux nginx mysql php first letter is LNMP